# Why doesn't event bubbling work in detached DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, dom-events

I have a parent `<div>` with one child `<div>` in memory - not attached to the current document. I want to trigger a `CustomEvent` on the child but listen to that event from the parent. Here is my code:

```
var parent = document.createElement('div');
var child = document.createElement('div');
parent.appendChild(child);
parent.addEventListener('boom', function(event) {
    console.log('parent listener', event); // <~ This never runs!
});
var event = new CustomEvent('boom', { bubbles: true });
child.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This code doesn't work as expected. The event listener on the parent never fires. This seems to be a contradiction of the JavaScript event system whereby events bubble up from the target. However, if I modify the final two lines of this snippet to the following, the callback fires as I would expect it to:

```
document.body.appendChild(parent);
child.dispatchEvent(event);
```

In other words, if I append my fragment as a subtree of the document before dispatching the event, then the parent event listener fires exactly as expected. Why? Is there a way to allow bubbling when using detached DOM elements?

Comment: I don't see any virtual DOM here, virtual DOM typically means DOM that's not really DOM - your DOM here is very real, just detached.

Comment: Also, here's a solution https://medium.com/@webprolific/bubbling-events-in-detached-dom-trees-35c34b551723 , if this solved the issue for you please write an answer for future visitors :)

Comment: @RobG it's the document object model, it represents how you interact with documents through an object API, an element with a child is definitely an object that specifies an interaction with the document, and the document is more than just the dom tree. AJAX and such are also parts of the DOM API and so are webworkers.

Comment: OK, revised title. Although... in practice, isn't "virtual DOM" often used colloquially simply to mean detached DOM elements?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum—should have put a humour emoticon there somewhere…

Comment: @GladstoneKeep Virtual dom typically means things like [React](https://github.com/facebook/react). RobG - there is no humour in StackOverflow, fun is banned :(

Comment: It does work as expected in Opera. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Bergi - It doesn't seem to work in Chrome 42.

Comment: @GladstoneKeep: Thanks. The article the Benjamin found mentions that it does work in FF and IE, so this seems to be a Chrome-only problem.

Comment: I have this problem on Safari (El Capitain). No event fired if the element is not attached to the DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why [doesn't bubbling work on detached elements]?

To answer your first question, I looked at the [W3C "UI Events (formerly DOM Level 3 Events)" spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/), and didn't see anything that addressed this issue specifically. However, the [event phase](http://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-phase) portion mentions a few things that makes this behavior seem reasonable.

> As the next step, the event object must complete one or more event phases. This specification defines three event phases: capture phase, target phase and bubble phase. Event objects complete these phases in the specified order using the partial propagation paths as defined below. **A phase must be skipped if it is not supported**, or if the event object's propagation has been stopped. For example, if the Event.bubbles attribute is set to false, the bubble phase will be skipped, and if Event.stopPropagation() has been called prior to the dispatch, all phases must be skipped.

Emphasis mine.

The spec then goes on to list the phases:

> 1. The **capture phase**: **The event object must propagate through the target's ancestors from the Window to the target's parent**. This phase is also known as the capturing phase. Event listeners registered for this phase must handle the event before it reaches its target.
> 2. The **target phase**: The event object must arrive at the event object's event target. This phase is also known as the at-target phase. Event listeners registered for this phase must handle the event once it has reached its target. If the event type indicates that the event must not bubble, the event object must halt after completion of this phase.
> 3. The **bubble phase**: **The event object propagates through the target's ancestors in reverse order, starting with the target's parent and ending with the Window**. This phase is also known as the bubbling phase. Event listeners registered for this phase must handle the event after it has reached its target.

Again, emphasis mine. The spec never calls out what happens with detached elements explicitly. Given that the target and bubble phases require the path to go from the element to the window, and that no path is possible on detached elements, it follows that the target and bubble event phases must be skipped because those paths are not supported.

> Is there a way to allow bubbling when using detached DOM elements?

As far as I can tell, there's nothing built-in that would allow bubbling. You might be able to fake bubbling with some custom code, but that would require checking whether the element is detached every time you trigger an event.

Another thought would be to add the elements to the DOM, trigger the event, and detach the elements. As I haven't tested this, I have no idea whether it would work.

Comment: My guess would be that the phrase is only there to make IE compatible which doesn't support capture phase.

Comment: This is a great answer, and I agree that although the spec isn't explicit about the behavior in this situation, it does make some sense that it doesn't occur. In any case, implementing event bubbling "manually" is simple enough: just dispatch the event object to every `parentNode`, starting from the desired target and traversing to the top of the detached tree.

Comment: @GladstoneKeep, it seems easy enough, but you still have to remember to assign the correct `target` and `currentTarget` properties to the event. To me it seems like a lot of overhead to support.