# Dispatch event to element bypassing capturing and bubbling

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events

Since `dispatchEvent`, as per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent), will apply the:

> normal event processing rules (including the capturing and optional
>   bubbling phase)

I'm looking for something similar but with a way to skip this process and trigger the event directly on the element. To trigger the default element event behavior while bypassing the processing stage.

As in, to capture the event at `window` level (before it reaches the other capture triggers) and pass it straight to the component (text area) invoking it directly.

(For example to trigger the default keydown of a text area without going through the hierarchy)

I've been trying to do it like this but if there is another event at window level this will not work:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyDown, true);

keyDown = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.nativeEvent && event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
      event.stopImmediatePropagation && event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      event.stopPropagation();

      // Pass event straight to the element

      return false;
  };
```

I'm looking to trigger the default element event behavior while bypassing the processing

Comment: are you thinking of stopPropagation()?

Comment: I'm looking into how to - after hijacking the event at window level - to trigger it directly on the element. I am indeed using `stopPropagation()` already.

Comment: Minimal producible code would help us figure out what your use case is, and how best to help you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may well be a more elegant way to do this, but one option is to remove the element from the DOM first, dispatch the event to it, then put it back into the DOM:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  console.log('body keydown capturing');
}, true);
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  console.log('body keydown bubbling');
});


const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  console.log('input keydown');
});
const node = document.createTextNode('');
input.replaceWith(node);
input.dispatchEvent(new Event('keydown'));
node.replaceWith(input);
```

```html
<input>
```

Since the element isn't in the DOM when the event is dispatched, the elements which *used* to be its ancestors won't see the event.

Note that events dispatched to detached elements [do not capture/bubble regardless](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29583766), not even to parents or children of element the event was dispatched to.

Without removing the element from the DOM entirely beforehand, if the input can exist in a shadow DOM, you can also dispatch an event to it there, and the event won't capture down or bubble up (though user input, not being custom events, will propagate through):

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  console.log('body keydown capturing');
}, true);
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  console.log('body keydown bubbling');
});


outer.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

const input = document.createElement('input');
outer.shadowRoot.append(input);
input.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  console.log('input keydown');
});

input.dispatchEvent(new Event('keydown'));
```

```html
<div id="outer"></div>
```

Another approach would be to call `stopPropagation` and `stopImmediatePropagation` in the *capturing* phase, at the very beginning, when the event is at the `window`, and then manually call the listener function you want. Make sure to attach *your* window listener before any other scripts on the page run, to make sure none of the page's listeners can see the event first:

```js
// Your script:
const input = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
input.className = 'custom-extension-element';
const handler = (e) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  });
};
window.addEventListener(
  'keydown',
  (e) => {
    if (e.target.closest('.custom-extension-element')) {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // Stop other capturing listeners on window from seeing event
      e.stopPropagation(); // Stop all other listeners
      handler(e);
    }
  },
  true // add listener in capturing phase
);


// Example page script
// which tries to attach listener to window in capturing phase:
window.addEventListener(
  'keydown',
  (e) => {
    console.log('page sees keydown');
  },
  true
);
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  console.log('body keydown capturing');
}, true);
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  console.log('body keydown bubbling');
});
```

Comment: This seems like the behavior I'm looking for but is there a way to get user input straight into a detached element?

Comment: "Straight into", what do you mean? The input has the event listener attached to it, so it needs to stay as-is, we can't create a different input. The input has to be manually detached so that it can be reattached (with `replaceWith`) at the same location once the event is dispatched.

Comment: A detached element will not trigger capturing and bubbling and that is what I'm looking for. But can I get user input into it without putting it in the DOM?

Comment: You can set its `value` with Javascript, but the user can't type into detached elements, because they're not in the DOM. This is a pretty odd thing to want to be doing. Usually, it'd make more sense to manage the parent listeners to make sure they don't cause problems.

Comment: There's also the shadow DOM, which you can configure such that certain events inside it don't bubble up https://javascript.info/shadow-dom-events

Comment: This is extension side code which will get injected into pages which I have no control over and is why I'm looking a way to implement this bypass. Shadow DOM would still allow the events to be captured no?

Comment: With the shadow DOM, if you want to use `dispatchEvent`, you *can* keep the event from going through the ancestors in the light DOM. But user input, not being from a custom event, *will* go throguh the light DOM.

Comment: If you want to prevent the page from handling user input from `keydown`, you can also attach your own capturing listener to the `window`, then call `stopPropagation` and `stopImmediatePropagation` if the target matches the element you want to observe

Comment: I think the last approach might work, but how do I pass the event directly to an element, I'd like to trigger it's default behavior (without attaching my own listener/handler)

Comment: What default behavior do you mean? If you need to run code when it occurs, call a function inside the capturing window listener when the target matches the element you need. If you require the event to make it down to the element, then page scripts may observer it as well, but you said you wanted to avoid that.

Comment: I need it to make it to the element without going through the captures of other listeners on the page and trigger the default behavior. For example, user presses key "u" inside a text box, I want to capture the event at window listener, stop propagation and activate the elements default behavior which is to get the user input and add "u" to the area.

Comment: Get the textbox via `e.target` and manually change its value by checking `event.key` and concatenating with the existing value at the appropriate position

Comment: This approach gets more problematic when the user wants to delete, paste, key combos  and so on.

Comment: Since you don't want the event to propagate and possibly trigger page listeners, it's your only real option. Either the event captures downwards, triggers listeners, and results in keys being registered on the input, or the event doesn't capture downwards, and you change the input value manually.

Answer (score 0):

The best way around propagation issues is to just execute the function:

```js
function tester(){
  console.log("Just fire the function! Don't dispatchEvent!");
}
tester();
document.getElementById('test').onkeyup = function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(this.id); console.log(e.target); tester();
}
document.body.onkeyup = ()=>{
  console.log("This shouldn't fire when on #test");
}
```

```html
<input id='test' type='text' value='' />
```

Comment: I'm looking to trigger the default element event behavior while bypassing the processing

Comment: No, for example the default `keydown` of a text area without going through the hierarchy

Comment: `eventObject.stopPropagation()`. You should use `keyup` if you want all the characters, by the way.